# Cant delete scheduled task with vbs

Tags: vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I create task with VBS, task create and run on time perfect

```
dim fso, f, pather, objShell
set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName)
pather = fso.GetParentFolderName(f)

controlTask = "schtasks /create /tn ""Controler"" /tr " & CHR(34) & pather & "\myFile.txt" & CHR(34) & " /sc minute /mo 50"
objShell.Run controlTask
```

And when I try to delete task

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "schtasks /delete /tn ""Controler"" /f"
```

the task is not deleted. Why is what?

If I create task with direct path to the file (`"schtasks /create /tn ""Controler"" /tr ""c:user\meme\myFile.txt"" /sc minute /mo 50"`), task create and delete. But my code assumes that "myFile.txt" travel with vbs file.

Comment: The `GetParentFolderName()` method does not get you the full path which `/tr` will be expecting so it can’t locate `myfile.txt` hence the error.

Comment: Try this command to find if exist the taskname Control  `schtasks /query | find /I "control"`

Comment: The [`/tr` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks) expects a full file path of the task file to run which [`GetParentFolderName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/22dyy47c(v=vs.84)) does not provide. That is the reason for the error. Before trying to make it run from VBScript go into the command prompt and run `schtasks` yourself and check the output there, including VBScript just adds an extra layer of complexity that is unnecessary until the issue is corrected.

Comment: I have no problem creating task, i have a problem deleting it

Comment: Did you try both a create then delete from the command prompt as suggested? Whether the create in VBScript works is irrelevant because the path you pass into it isn’t a full file path.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is the way. i could not delete it and i disable it

```
 oShell.Run "SCHTASKS /CHANGE /TN ""Control"" /DISABLE"
```